# Handle Ctrl-Alt-Delete in Fullscreen Window

Tags: c++, windows

I want to change from a fullscreen window to a regular window whenever the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>, similar to how DirectX 11 behaves on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.  A quick Google search reveals that there is no direct windows message for this key combination.  Is there a more general message that describes both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> that I can intercept so that my program can react accordingly?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, your window should lose focus when either happens, so detect that?

Comment: @MicroVirus That's probably the answer, then (WM_KILLFOCUS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more general message I was looking for was `WM_KILLFOCUS`.